# VB6 Bitwise And converted to c# as boolean result

Tags: c#, vb6, bit

If I have in VB6:

```
GetBit = 414 And 2 ^ 0
```

GetBit will be equal to false because the return type of the function is boolean. I'm not sure how vb6 is coming up with false though?

How can I convert this to c#?

```
long longResult = 0;
longResult = 414 & 2 ^ 0;

return Convert.ToBoolean(longResult);
```

^ The above c# code returns me true where longResult is 2. I do understand how 2 is calculated but I'm not sure how/why false is returned in the vb6 code?

Comment: Yeah when I step through it GetBit is false. Now the 414 is a parameter of the function of type 'variant' and when the function is called the orig writer casted the value to a Long CLng(). So I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it or not??

Comment: I don't have VB6 anymore, so can't try to reproduce.  Sorry.

Comment: Yeah, i stepped through the Vb6 code again and set it to an integer and sure enough it was 0 which would be false. I'm clueless on why though. Thanks for the input though. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ^ operator in Basic is Math.Pow().  So in VB6 it is evaluated as 414 & Math.Pow(2, 0) == 0x19E & 1 = 0 == False.  Note how raising an integer literal to the power of 0 is not very useful, the result is always 1.

In C#, the ^ operator is the XOR operator, not the same thing.  Just use 1.

Closer scrutiny is certainly warranted.  It is not the kind of code you'd want to blindly transliterate, decent odds you are just reproducing a bug.

---

> So really code is: long result = firstParam & Math.Pow(2, secondParam);

No.  Keep in mind that `Long` in VB6 is a 32-bit integer, you want `int` in C#.  And you really don't want to use floating point math.  Proper conversion is:

```
  int result = firstParam & (1 << secondParam);
```

Comment: Thanks Hans. I finally realized ^ in c# wasn't the same thing. Once I switched it to use Math.Pow it worked as expected. I would use 1 but this code is in a function 0 is a parameter. So really code is:
 
        long result = firstParam & Math.Pow(2, secondParam);

Comment: Don't do that, use `firstParam & (1 << secondParam)`.   A VB6 Long is `int` in C#.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the help Hans. Good call on the VB6 long being a 32bit int in c#. Forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: I had totally overlooked that ^ in C# is XOR and not Pow(), very embarrassing. I decided to leave my answer because the VB6 solution is still correct, and because of the two links to the pages with the operator precedences.

**Original post**: Classical operator precedence issue ;-) C# and VB6 have differences in that.

In VB6, bitwise operators have lower preference than arithmetic operators, see [Operator Precedence in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw84t893.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). So what happens is 2 ^ 0 evaluates to 1, and 414 And 1 is 0.

The solution to get True is:

```
GetBit = (414 And 2) ^ 0
```

For completeness' sake, you can find the C# operator precedences [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx). Turns out, & is just one step higher than ^ in C#.

Comment: In case anybody wants to try this but doesn't have VB6 available, I reproduced this with VBA of Office 2013.